# Cannot load cvs file in jupyter as well as in pycharm. How to load file?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from math import sqrt


def read_file(fileName):
    with open(fileName) as file:
        metadata = [next(file) for i in range(6)]
        title = metadata[0].split('=')[1]
        institution = metadata[1].split('=')[1]
        references = metadata[2].split('=')[1]
        comment = metadata[3].split('=')[1]
        trend = metadata[4].split('=')[1]
        cols = metadata[5].split(',')
        cols[4] = cols[4].rstrip()
        header = {
            'title': title,
            'institution': institution,
            'references': references,
            'comment': comment,
            'trend': trend
        }
        data = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=',', dtype='float', names=cols)
        data['merge'] = data['TOPX/Poseidon'].combine_first(data['Jason-1']).combine_first(
            data['Jason-2']).combine_first(data['Jason-3'])
    return header, data
```

Comment: Do *not* post links to images of text. Post *that in the question itself as formatted text*

Answer (score 0):

pass full path of your file as argument in that `file open` part

```
(r"C:\Path\to\your\file.csv)
```

Or you might want to use `os.path` package to pass the path of your csv as argument

```
os.path.realpath(__file__)
```